# How to overlay/embed bootstrap button on image?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have been searching the web but can't find the answer.  Is it possible to overlay or embed a bootstrap button over/in an image?  If so, how?

I have a image that I want to overlay a bootstrap button over so it looks like it is embedded in the image.  I would like the button to have a dynamic label on it(for ex. somebody's name).

Comment: You might want to take a look at http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Comment: Thanks Stano.  That looks like it should work.

Comment: I'm still learning how this answer/approve question stuff works :)  Most times I it says I have to wait 2 days and I forget. thanks again

Comment: Glad it helped, and yeah this is very huge and complex website to discover and so it's all right ;-)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Stano answered the question for me!

"...yes the button can be positioned above the image tag, for example like this: http://jsfiddle.net/ubWuX"

**HTML:**

```
<div id="img_container">
    <img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/initializing.png"/>
    <button class="button"> click here </button>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#img_container {
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:center;
    border:1px solid red;
}

.button {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:10px;
    right:10px;
    width:100px;
    height:30px;
}
```